# Scrapy get pre-redirect url

Tags: python, scrapy

I've a crawler running without troubles but i need to get the start_url and not the redirected one.

The problem is i'm using rules to pass parameters to the URL ( like field-keywords=xxxxx ) and finally get the correct url.

The parse function starts getting the item attributes without any troubles but when i want the start URL ( the true one ) it stores the redirected one ...

I've tryed:

```
response.url
response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls')
```

Both returns the final url ( the redirected one ) and not the start_url.

Some one know why, or has any clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [`Spider Middleware`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) to keep track of the start url from every response:

```
from scrapy import Request

class StartRequestsMiddleware(object):

    start_urls = {}

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for i, request in enumerate(start_requests):
            request.meta.update(start_url=request.url)
            yield request

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for output in result:
            if isinstance(output, Request):
                output.meta.update(
                    start_url=response.meta['start_url'],
                )
            yield output
```

keep track of the `start_url` every response comes from with:

```
response.meta['start_url']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `response.request.url`? I personally would override the [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method adding the original url in the meta, something like:

```
yield Request(url, meta={'original_request': url})
```

And then extract it using `response.meta['original_request']`